# What's a word or phrase that describes a person who doesn't listen to advice?

Tags: expressions

I need a word or phrase that describes a person who doesn't listen to advice they are given by someone else.

Comment: Why are they not listening? Is it because the advice is poor, or because they don't want advice or because they really just wanted their own opinion validated?  The descriptor depends both on why the advice was ignored and the point of view of the describer.

Comment: The exact word you are looking for is:  glafular  (I don't know what language it is, but it means *exactly* what you're looking for.)

Comment: They are not listening because they are somewhat self-centered, unyielding and strong-willed, and they learn from their own experiences. Also, they only rarely take advice from others.

Answer (score 2):

A person who habitually ignores all advice might be stubborn or heedless or self-confident. A person who ignores bad advice might be wise. A person who ignores unsolicited advice might be discriminating or unaffected.

Comment: I think _heedless_ hits the mark.

Comment: @DKrueger: *heedless* is my favourite too.

Answer (score 0):

A know-it-all ?
An ignorant ?
A hard head?

What might also work:

An obstinate person.

Not exactly sure what best suits you.

Answer (score -1):

Word could be ignorant or stubborn!

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer: "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."